# application menu disappeared from several applications. how to get it back

Tags: gnome, appmenu

application menus did disappear. not all applications.

applications affected are for example: Gedit, Gimp, software center, Empathy

applications not affected: Synaptic, Clementine, Libre Office.

screenshot: [image]

using gnome shell, ubuntu 11.10. how can i get it back?

thanks .

Comment: Do you  run the global-menu extension?

Comment: i have it installed but not activated.

Comment: oh, i did remove the extension itself and now it is ok. even if it is not activated through advanced settings. thanks for the hint. please right the answer as an actual one, so i can give you credit and mark it as solved for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete global-menu.

Please see [this post on webupd8 for how to disable global-menu](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-gnome-shell-global-menu-in.html)